# Как обойти CORS

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, ecmascript-6

Пытаюсь с помощью js забрать ленту RSS следующим способом:

```js
'use strict';
var rss = 'https://habrahabr.ru/rss/feed/posts/eeb96d62f10f118dbc9ac3747022f16b/';

var result = document.querySelector('#result');
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "text/plain");
myHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
fetch(rss, {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: null,
  cache: 'default'
}).then(function(response) {
  return response.text();
}).then(function(res) {
  let parser = new DOMParser();
  let xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/xml");
  result.innerHTML = xmlDoc;
  console.log(xmlDoc);
}).catch((error) => {
  result.innerHTML += error;
  console.log
});
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Failed to load
>   https://habrahabr.ru/rss/feed/posts/eeb96d62f10f118dbc9ac3747022f16b/:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://localhost.local' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Если воспользоваться [расширением для хрома](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), то данные приходят без ошибок. Пробовал добавить те же значения в запрос что и добавляет расширение, но это не прокатило. Почему расширение может обойти CORS?
Что необходимо добавить в заголовок, что бы можно было получить данные?

Comment: может быть jsonp ? )

Comment: @SultanovShamil habr его поддерживает?

Comment: Это правило ограничения домена. Расширение подделывает разрешение сайта использовать CORS.

Comment: *Пробовал добавить те же значения в запрос* – гы, ну естественно, они ведь должны быть в **ответе** на этот запрос.